# Prove that if G is a digraph who underlying graph is regular, then then following formula holds.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

> Prove that if $G$ is a digraph whose underlying graph is regular, then $$\sum_{i=1}^n\operatorname{outdeg}^2(v_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n\operatorname{indeg}^2(v_i)\;.$$

This is a assignment problem, so please don't directly give me the solution.
I have almost no idea about this problem, what I know is:

1. The Handshaking Dilemma: $$m=\sum_{i=1}^n\operatorname{outdeg}(v_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n\operatorname{indeg}(v_i)$$
2. What an underlying graph is.
3. Since it is $k$-regular, that means for every vertex $v_i$ in $G$, $\operatorname{outdeg}(v_i)+\operatorname{indeg}(v_i)= k$.

Hints are appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sum of squares of in-degrees vs out-degrees in a Tournament Graph](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6873/sum-of-squares-of-in-degrees-vs-out-degrees-in-a-tournament-graph)

Comment: @onesevenfour: Not quite: mostly because this one definitely asks for only a hint, while the other has complete answers, but also because this one is slightly more general.

Comment: Isn't the hint basically the answer?  I guess this one is also slightly more general since it is not only tournament graphs, but doesn't the same method still apply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\operatorname{outdeg}^2(v_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n\operatorname{indeg}^2(v_i)$$

if and only if

$$\begin{align*}
0&=\sum_{i=1}^n\operatorname{outdeg}^2(v_i)-\sum_{i=1}^n\operatorname{indeg}^2(v_i)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\operatorname{outdeg}^2(v_i)-\operatorname{indeg}^2(v_i)\right)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\big(\operatorname{outdeg}(v_i)-\operatorname{indeg}(v_i)\big)\big(\operatorname{outdeg}(v_i)+\operatorname{indeg}(v_i)\big)\\
&=k\sum_{i=1}^n\big(\operatorname{outdeg}(v_i)-\operatorname{indeg}(v_i)\big)\;,
\end{align*}$$

where the underlying graph is $k$-regular.